# Using eval() with np.array and scipy.signal.welch() function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, eval

I am trying to use eval() with a function from the library Scipy.

I an using a numpy array.

Here are the different types :

```
print(type(cptrace))
print(type(cptrace.data))
print(type(cptrace.data[0]))
```

It's return me

```
<class 'obspy.core.trace.Trace'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.int32'>
```

cptrace.data is kind of [323 322 320 ... 177 175 175]

I want to apply scipy.signal.welch function on my data.

When i do y directly it works fine :

```
f, pxx= scipy.signal.welch(cptrace)
```

But in fact i need to use eval() because the type of function can be different and choosed by a user via a dropdown menu.

So i tryied

```
f, pxx= eval("scipy.signal.welch("+cptrace.data+")")
```

which returned :

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      9 print(type(cptrace.data[0]))
     10 
---> 11 f, pxx= eval("scipy.signal.welch("+cptrace.data+")")

TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('

I also tryied

```
f, pxx= eval("scipy.signal.welch("+np.array_repr(cptrace.data)+")")
```

This time, i got :

---

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      9 print(type(cptrace.data[0]))
     10 
---> 11 f, pxx= eval("scipy.signal.welch("+np.array_repr(cptrace.data)+")")

string in module()

NameError: name 'int32' is not defined

I realy don't know how to solve my problem.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Stop using `eval` to parse strings. Create explicit mappings from user inputs to the data you need.

Comment: Tks for your answer. Since I am new in Python, do you have any example on the way to do it ?